# "Door design" or "doors design" or "door designs"?

Tags: plural-forms, compound-nouns

I have trouble with compound nouns plural. What would be appropriate to write ?

> Animals set as door design.

or

> Animals set as doors design.

or

> Animals set as door designs.

Context would be a neighborhood where people have animals engraved on their front doors.

Answer (score 1):

Plurality would more commonly be indicated by making design plural: "Animals set as door designs."